# Make backward nesting in scss?

Tags: nested, sass

Is there a way to nest backwards in scss?
In **css** when I want to override style becourse of IE or other browser specific styles I like the selector to be right after the style it selector it overrides. Like this

**css**

```
.class-a .class-b{ color: pink }
.ie6 .class-a .class-b{ color: blue}
```

Is that possible in scss? Because right now I write it like this (and I dont like it)

**scss**

```
.class-a{
  .class-b { color: pink }
  .othercss { bla bla bla: sdfsd }
  .fsdfsd { dfsdfs: sdfsd }
  }
}

body.ie7 .class-a .class-b{ color:blue }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `&` parent selector.

```
.class-a{
  .class-b { 
    color: pink;
    .ie7 & {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
  .othercss { bla bla bla: sdfsd }
  .fsdfsd { dfsdfs: sdfsd }
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_

Comment: Awesome I knew & but didn't knew it could be used like that! http://jsfiddle.net/lajlev/EwtVS/2/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found this possible, no.

On a side note if you need to add too many styles addressed directly to IE7+8 etc. there's most likely a better cross-browser way to do it, I haven't found it to be a problem having to do a few old IE specific nesting trees in my projects so far.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I still can't believe that there isn't a solution to this matter.